# is there a type of number disjoint complex numbers

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

is there a type of number disjoint complex numbers?

Has anyone found a type of number or is there exists such number s.t. $\omega^*$ (or something else) that $\omega^*\not\in\mathbb{C}$ but grouped in a new type of number with its meanings such as $\omega^*\in\mathbb{G_z}$

Comment: like [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{G}_Z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out hypercomplex numbers in Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number